# How to hide / show component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm developing a small application in `VueJs` where I'm having a div element and trying to show element if the data value is 1 and hide if the data value is 0, for this I'm having v-model as `withClient` something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">With client*:</label>
    <div class="radio col-sm-3">
        <input type="radio" name="with_client" v-model="withClient" value="1" checked="">
        <label>
            Yes
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio col-sm-3">
        <input type="radio" name="with_client" v-model="withClient" value="0">
        <label>
            No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the element which needs to be hidden:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Clients:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8" v-if="withClientSelection">
        <v-select
                multiple
                :options="contactClients"
                :on-search="getOptions"
                placeholder="Client name"
                v-model="clientParticipants">
        </v-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've computed property as `withClientSelection`:

```
withClientSelection() {
    if(this.withClient === 0)
    {
        this.clientParticipants = ''
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

But somehow I'm not able to get this. Help me on this. Thanks

Comment: The question is not about enable/disable, it is about hide/show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very simple, you should use

```
this.withClient === '0'
```

instead of

```
this.withClient === 0
```

I also overlooked this part and verified your code myself first, here's a fully working example that I used.

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    withClient: '0',
    clientParticipants: '',
    dummyData: ['Aaron', 'Bart', 'Charles', 'Dora', 'Edward', 'Flora', 'Gladys', 'Heidi', 'Iris', 'Jason'],
    contactClients: []
  },
  computed: {
    withClientSelection() {
      if (this.withClient === '0') {
        return false
      }
      return true
    }
  },
  watch: {
    withClient(newVal) {
      if (newVal === 0) {
        this.clientParticipants = '';
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getOptions(search, loading) {
      /*
      loading(true)
      this.$http.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories', {
         q: search
      }).then(resp => {
         this.contactClients = resp.data.items
         loading(false)
      })
      */
      this.contactClients = this.dummyData
        .filter((name) => name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.4"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">With client*:</label>
    <div class="radio col-sm-3">
        <input type="radio" name="with_client" v-model="withClient" value="1" checked="">
        <label>
            Yes
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio col-sm-3">
        <input type="radio" name="with_client" v-model="withClient" value="0">
        <label>
            No
        </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Clients:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8" v-if="withClientSelection === true">
        <v-select
                multiple
                :options="contactClients"
                :on-search="getOptions"
                placeholder="Client name"
                v-model="clientParticipants">
        </v-select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Selected Clients:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8" v-if="withClientSelection === true">
      {{clientParticipants}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Nitish Kumar I also noticed you modified `clientParticipants` inside the computed property, better separate the logic for better debugging.

Comment: Thanks.. It helped

Answer (score 0):

I think the intention with v-model on hidden inputs is to set up a one-way binding, in which case it's much better to use 
`<input type="hidden" :value="someData" >`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will help you to solve your problem.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    clientParticipants: '',
    withClientSelection: 1
  },
  methods: {
    checkMe: function(type) {
    return this.withClientSelection = type
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">With client*:</label>
    <div class="radio col-sm-3">
        <input type="radio" name="with_client" @change="checkMe(1)" checked="">
        <label>
            Yes
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio col-sm-3">
        <input type="radio" name="with_client" @change="checkMe(0)">
        <label>
            No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Clients:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8" v-if="withClientSelection">
      Display now!
        <v-select
                multiple
                :options="contactClients"
                :on-search="getOptions"
                placeholder="Client name"
                v-model="clientParticipants">
        </v-select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using `v-model="withClient"` as I need it while storing the database.

Comment: you can add `v-model="withClient"`. I'm sorry.